# Limit of functions in one variable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that

1. $x(t)$ is a function defined on $[0, \infty]$ such that $x(t) \in [a, b]$ for all $t \geq 0$.
2. $f(x)$ is a continuous function and bounded on $[a, b]$.
3. $f(x(t)) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.
4. The set $f^{-1}(0)$ has only finite element $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, $x_i \in [a, b]$.

Can we prove that $x(t)$ has also finite limit as $t \to \infty$???

Comment: Yes because $x(t)\in [a,b]$?

Comment: @Tony S.F Thank you for your answer. Please, write your answer in more detail.

Comment: Do you want $\lim_{t \to \infty}x(t)$ to exist? It might not exist because you did not require $x$ to be continuous.
Tony S.F. was saying that the limit, if it existed, would have to be finite because $x(t) \in [a,b]$ is inside a bounded set.

Comment: @user357980 Thank you for your response. Here, we can suppose that $x(t)$ is continuous. Can we conclude that $\lim x(t)$ exist?

Comment: What would the limit of $x(t)$ have to be if it existed?